# Distribution function of random variable Y = 2X - 1

Tags: probability

I have this question, i've managed to Solve a),

[image: Question & Answer]

(By the way - Distribution function should be Fx(x) = $P(X \leq x)$ 
And the Probability function should be like the answer suggests, P(=m), no?)

Anyway - I don't understand b), i've tried to make a table for Y:

$X \quad = 0 \quad|\quad 1 \quad|\quad 2 \quad|\quad 3 \quad|\quad 4 \quad|\quad 5$

P(X) = $\frac{32}{243} \quad| \quad\frac{80}{243} \quad|\quad \frac{80}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{40}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{10}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{1}{243}$

$Y\quad = -1 \quad|\quad 1\quad |\quad 3\quad |\quad 5\quad | \quad7\quad |\quad 9   $

$P(Y) =  0 \quad|\quad \frac{80}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{40}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{1}{243} \quad|\quad 0 \quad| \quad0 $

But sum of P(Y) $\neq$ 1 so it's WRONG.

I understand that if $Y = 2X - 1$ so $X = \frac{y+1}{2}$ 
And then by the formula in a) solution, I can replace m with $X = \frac{y+1}{2}$ and then the answer is identical. 
But I don't understand WHY should I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confused as to the $P(Y)$'s. Since we are looking at the distribution $Y=2X-1$, we have that $P(Y)=P(2X-1)$ so $P(Y=-1)=P(2X-1=-1)=P(X=0)=\frac{32}{243}$ and so on. Thus your table should look like

$Y\quad = -1 \quad|\quad 1\quad |\quad 3\quad |\quad 5\quad | \quad7\quad |\quad 9$

$P(Y) =  \frac{32}{243} \quad| \quad\frac{80}{243} \quad|\quad \frac{80}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{40}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{10}{243}\quad | \quad\frac{1}{243}$

We have merely replaced the values of $X$ with the new $Y$ values and the $P(Y=k)$ corresponds to $P(2X-1=k)$.

Comment: You are right, but still i'm not sure about p(Y=k).

When I think about it, it might be the reason:

Because Y = 2X - 1, 
P(Y = k) = P(2X - 1) = P(2X = K+1) = P(X = (K+1)/2 ), and I have P(X = m), so I need to replace m with (K+1)/2 to get the right probabilities. :)

Comment: Your reason is correct. Do you understand now?

Comment: Yes thanks, I accepted ur answer